# What are the elements from Chinese philosophy that can be found in Shota Rustaveli's poetry?

Tags: inspiration, georgian-language, shota-rustaveli

The [German Wikipedia article about Shota Rustaveli](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schota_Rustaweli), author of the Georgian medieval epic poem [*The Knight in the Panther's Skin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knight_in_the_Panther%27s_Skin) claims,

> Seine Dichtung spiegelt chinesische, persische und griechische Philosophie wider.

Translation:

> His poetry reflects [elements of?] Chinese, Persian and Greek philosophy.

[According to legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shota_Rustaveli#Biography), Rustaveli received some of his education in the Byzantine Empire, so the elements from Greek philosophy don't sound far-fetched. One of the other great empires of the period was the [Khwarazmian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khwarazmian_Empire), which covered Persia (in addition to a large area east of the Caspian Sea), so contacts with Persian philosophy don't seem far-fetched either.

What we now know as China, however, was ruled by the [Southern Song dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty#Southern_Song,_1127%E2%80%931279) in the south, the [Jin dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234)) in the northeast and the [Western Xia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Xia) in the northwest, so Han Chinese culture was in retreat. The [Silk Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road) did not pass through the Kingdom of Georgia, or at least the main routes didn't, so it is not obvious how Shota Rustaveli would have learnt about Chinese culture or philosophy.

Assuming that the statement in the German Wikipedia article is correct, what elements of Chinese philosophy can be identified in Shota Rustaveli's work?